# Apply unique ID to events where i = j and j = i

Tags: r, dataframe

In the following table:

```
set.seed(5)
df <- data.frame(year=rep(c(2010:2011), each=8),
                 i=rep(c('66','66','6','6','65','65','6','6'), times=2),
                 j=rep(c('66','6','66','6','65','6','65','6'), times=2),
                 count=round(runif(8, 0, 5),0))
```

There are several events where `'i = j'` and `'i != j'`, I am trying to assign unique values to each of these events. In one scenario where `'i = j'` (i.e. `66 = 66` or `6 = 6`) I want to assign the value as '0'. However, if `'i != j'` I want to assign that event as `'1'` or higher depending on each unique group e.g., `'66_6'` or `'6_66'` is assigned a `'1'` and `'65_6'` or `'6_65'` is assigned a `'2'`.

So far, I've only been able to figure out how to filter this table to include where these events, such as in the case of group 1 or 2, appear.

```
x <- df[paste(df$i,df$j,sep = "_") != paste(sapply(strsplit(paste(df$j,df$i,sep = "_"), "\\s+"), function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse=" ")),sep=""),]
```

If anyone has any advice on how to proceed, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to `paste` (`str_c` - from `stringr`), the row wise minimum, maximum (`pmin/pmax` respectively) of 'i', 'j' columns, get the index of `unique` elements, and `replace` those where `i` is not equal to `j`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    mutate(ij =str_c(pmin(i, j), pmax(i, j), sep="_"),
    new = +(i != j), 
     new = replace(new, new ==1, match(ij[new ==1],
        unique(ij[new == 1]))), ij = NULL)
```

-output

```
    year  i  j count new
1  2010 66 66     1   0
2  2010 66  6     3   1
3  2010  6 66     5   1
4  2010  6  6     1   0
5  2010 65 65     1   0
6  2010 65  6     4   2
7  2010  6 65     3   2
8  2010  6  6     4   0
9  2011 66 66     1   0
10 2011 66  6     3   1
11 2011  6 66     5   1
12 2011  6  6     1   0
13 2011 65 65     1   0
14 2011 65  6     4   2
15 2011  6 65     3   2
16 2011  6  6     4   0
```

---

or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, new := 0][i != j, new := match(paste(pmin(i, j),
     pmax(i, j), sep="_"), unique(paste(pmin(i, j), pmax(i, j), sep="_")))]
```

-output

```
> df
    year  i  j count new
 1: 2010 66 66     1   0
 2: 2010 66  6     3   1
 3: 2010  6 66     5   1
 4: 2010  6  6     1   0
 5: 2010 65 65     1   0
 6: 2010 65  6     4   2
 7: 2010  6 65     3   2
 8: 2010  6  6     4   0
 9: 2011 66 66     1   0
10: 2011 66  6     3   1
11: 2011  6 66     5   1
12: 2011  6  6     1   0
13: 2011 65 65     1   0
14: 2011 65  6     4   2
15: 2011  6 65     3   2
16: 2011  6  6     4   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `data.table` option using `.GRP`

```
setDT(df)[
  , new := .GRP * (i != j),
  paste0(pmin(i, j), "_", pmax(i, j))
][
  ,
  new := as.integer(factor(new)) - 1
]
```

which gives

```
> df
    year  i  j count new
 1: 2010 66 66     1   0
 2: 2010 66  6     3   1
 3: 2010  6 66     5   1
 4: 2010  6  6     1   0
 5: 2010 65 65     1   0
 6: 2010 65  6     4   2
 7: 2010  6 65     3   2
 8: 2010  6  6     4   0
 9: 2011 66 66     1   0
10: 2011 66  6     3   1
11: 2011  6 66     5   1
12: 2011  6  6     1   0
13: 2011 65 65     1   0
14: 2011 65  6     4   2
15: 2011  6 65     3   2
16: 2011  6  6     4   0
```